# Monitoring session views for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, express-session

I currently have a chrome extension that GET's javascript from my node.js server. However the javascript file I want to serve will depend on the number of times https://www.google.co.uk/ has been visited.

I want to perform this on the server side, so a solution such as express sessions might work. However the extension is not based on the server, so how could this work?

I would like to avoid sending cookies to a database and constantly checking the number to initiate the relevant javascript file.

Comment: Exactly in situations like this I take a pen and paper. Which information is taking which way?

Comment: My server needs to be able to count the number of times a URL is visited, and then send a script for a given number, e.g. 10 visits to  https://www.google.co.uk/ returns tenvisits.js to the chrome extension.